# Android Emulator closed because of an internal error: Vulkan Driver

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, vulkan, vdi

I'm currently in the process of setting up my Android Studio.
I created a custom virtual device which runs on Android 8.1 and uses the 'Software GLES2.0' option for the graphics setting. I have also enabled the Windows Hypervisor Platform feature in my Windows Features.

When I try to boot the device via the button in Android Studio, nothing happens. When I try to run it via the console it takes a few seconds before showing the following screen:
[Vulkan Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6E7c.png)

I am working through a VDI which connects to an AMD Epyc Server. I assume the issue might have something to do with this because it works fine when I run the emulator on the host pc (without using VDI), however this removes my access to the codebase and is not a viable solution.

I was wondering if I can fix this problem myself, or if I should contact the server administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error, reboot of my Mac with Catalina fixed it.

I think a few days ago the emulator was updated and I saw no instructions to reboot my machine, but that sometimes helps and so I tried.